# Как входить на сервер по ssh, не вводя пароль пользователя

Tags: ssh

Я вхожу на сервер по ssh следующим образом: "ssh username@domain". После нажатия клавиши enter сервер запрашивает пароль. Есть ли какая-нибудь опция или способ, чтобы не вводить постоянно пароль? Ключа у меня нету.

Comment: сгенерировать ключ и ходить через него

Comment: Как это сделать? Сервер не мой

Comment: ssh-keygen (с пустым паролем) + ssh-copy-id

Comment: Выдаёт **/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found**

Comment: `Сервер не мой` — генерировать секретный ключ надо не на сервере, а на вашей рабочей машине.